# Magento: Newsletters not going out

Tags: magento, cron, newsletter

The problem i have is that i have created newsletter template, added few subscribers and i can add the template with subscribers into queue - all that works fine.

I can also run the cron.php from the browser - it runs without errors, but the damn e-mails are not going out anyway. For that reason i have not done the crontab -e and added the stuff into that file yet. As far as i see - it does not matter where you execute the file from - be it crontab, shell or browser - it should work in any case. And i can see that it is not working.

Any ideas?

Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest you take a look at the cron_schedule table of your database ?
As soon as the cron.php file has been called (should it be via crontab or via a browser request), there must be a line added to the table. The line is "newsletter_send_all".

If a previous "neswsletter_send_all" was scheduled it should be run and its status set to "success" and the new one to "pending". Or, if there's a problem, the warning message is stored in the cron_schedule table on the same line as the newsletter_send_all that failed.

If when running cron.php the cron_schedule table is not appended with a new line, there may be a problem with the config.xml file of the Newsletter module or with your cron settings in the admin configuration. About that last subject see : http://www.jnorton.co.uk/blog/setting-magento-cron-system

All the above may give you a few tracks.

Comment: My programmer found solution following your pointers. thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Are any emails being sent from Magento? (such as order confirmations)? If not, you might need to setup your email sending options or the outgoing email settings on the server.

Comment: Yes they are. Emails sent by magento are going out just fine. All order confirmations or feedback form stuff are going very nice. 
what i was referring to is that the letters do not dissappear from the queue - they remain there no matter how often or how many times the cron.php has been run.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Configuration>Admin>Security, select “No” in “Add Secret Key to URLs”, save configuration.

Src: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/2424/P105/#